# Getting attribute info from OpenLayers (QGIS2Web)

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis2web

The below files are generated from QGIS2Web tool and altered by me, I generated the OpenLayers code using QGIS2Web. The problem is not showing the pop-up(attribute information) for multiple Layer files. For a single file pop-up function is working fine (I attached the screenshot with pop-up).

I would like to show my attribute details on the right side of the panel(permanent) when the user clicked the particular polygon.

How to customize based on my need?

[image: single layer with pop-up of attribute information]

The above pic shows the pop-up function (working fine for single layer).

[image: Multiple layer file didn't show the attribute information]

The above pic shows the multiple layer structure. I want to show attribute information for the topmost visible layer.

Comment: It may depend on how you are implementing the layers in OpenLayers. For both raster and vector layers you could use `map.forEachLayerAtPixel()` to identify the non-transparent layers where the user clicked, then select the topmost in the layer stack.  For vectors you could also use `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer){ ... })`; where the callback is passed the feature and its layer.

Comment: I used QGIS2Web tool for generating the layers in OpenLayers, so I don't know where to change my code. I'm a beginner for OpenLayers. so can you please give me some more idea.